# Allure combine index.html does not exists

Tags: python, allure

So in my project I have thie `reports` directory when all `.json` files generated and at the end I can use the `command` `allure serve .\reports\` and see my `HTML` report file.
After quick search I found `allure-combine` module that creates single `HTML` file builder and after my tests finished I try to run the command `allure-combine .\reports\` but got this error:

> Exception: ERROR: File .\reports\index.html doesnt exists, but it
> should!

According [allure-combine](https://pypi.org/project/allure-combine/) I should use this `command`:

```
allure-combine ./some/path/to/allure/generated/folder
```

So in my case it should be `allure-combine .\reports`

This `index.html` does not exist in my folder - What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I remeber something in HTML about if you put a forward slash at the start of the link linking it to another page it will search in the root instead of in your folders, so try removing the forward slash at the start, so it would be File .reports\index.html

Comment: According the guide I should use this command: allure-combine ./some/path/to/allure/generated/folder (allure-combine .\reports\          in my case)